# Nginx-ingress wont create loadbalancer on EKS1.2x

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I've done the steps on https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#tls-termination-in-aws-load-balancer-nlb.

I've updated the arn with my cert and set the vpc cidr.
I used https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/basic-usage/ as a template for a single url and pod.

I expect once the ingress controller is running, it would create the nlb.. but it just doesnt seem to do it. I've never got this working since eks1.18 and actually ended-up starting new clusters at eks1.18 and then upgrading them from there...less then ideal.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to where i can look to see why the controller doesnt seem to be creating the nlb? The external ip for the lb is always listed as pending and i dont know why.

Comment: The ingress controller does not create the load balancer, that's handled by k8s itself when it sees a service with type of `LoadBalancer` (which your nginx-ingress service should be). On EKS you often also want the [aws-load-balancer-controller](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/aws-load-balancer-controller.html) otherwise load balancer creation options are more limited.

Comment: check the service which is type loadbalancer, `kubectl describe servicename` and you will able to see the error that not letting the Kubernetes to create loadbalancer

Comment: Not very detailed :( I think i'm going to look at the aws controller, like suggested above. 

Normal  EnsuringLoadBalancer  109s (x185 over 14h)  service-controller  Ensuring load balancer

Comment: Awww man, it was because of this: https://github.com/weaveworks/eksctl/issues/3341 . I added the tag for my cluster and the nlb built right away.